# How to Serving static files with express if it is inside a subdirectory

Tags: express, backend, static-files

I am having trouble with serving a html file which is inside a subdirectory inside public folder.
My directory structure looks like:

```
public/
      HTML/
           index.html
index.js
```

I want to serve the index.html for the root route.

This doesn't work:

```
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

Comment: Why not just leave index.html in the root folder and work from there? That is sort of the goal of any index file

Comment: currently doing that only .Just wanted to make it more organised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), this should be enough:

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

It also gives you such example

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

It doesn't go much further other than explaining how you can set up multiple public directories. Anyway, it has worked for me in my projects.

Perhaps you need to state directly `app.use(express.static('html'))` or `app.use(express.static('public/html'))`. Let me know what works for you.